# NullPointerException while loading a class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The following code gives NullPointerException:

```
badOb = Class.forName("sample");
        try {
            Object obj = badOb .newInstance();
        } catch (ThreadDeath e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (expectedException.isInstance(e)) {
                out.println("Expected runtime exception: " + e);
                return 0;
            } else {
                out.println("Unexpected runtime exception: " + e);
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

But when I add a print statement like:

```
 badOb = Class.forName("sample");
         out.println("hello");
        try {
            Object obj = badOb .newInstance();
        } catch (ThreadDeath e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (expectedException.isInstance(e)) {
                out.println("Expected runtime exception: " + e);
                return 0;
            } else {
                out.println("Unexpected runtime exception: " + e);
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

It works ok and give the expected exception.

I checked and the badob object is not NULL. When I look at the bytecode, the following lines are extra on adding the print statement:

```
aload_3        
ldc     #19; //String  hello           
invokevirtual   #1
```

Can someone help me make sense of it?

My java environment is:

```
 java version "1.5.0"
 Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition
```

**Edit:**
It also works as expected if I introduce a delay of a few seconds instead of the print statement.

Comment: Which line throws exception? BTW why are you using a very old JVM?

Comment: What does the actual class do?

Comment: Where is stacktrace? What is `expectedException`?

Comment: And what is class `sample`? Why don't you show us real code?

Comment: I have no idea why do people upvote such strange questions

Comment: @MiserableVariable: The issue am facing is more or less the same as this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4171827. But for version 1.5

Comment: You may or may not but if you need help here you need to give more details

Comment: @MiserableVariable: I cant post my entire code here. Can you instead please help make sense of the last comment by Coleen Phillimore at the link I posted above? It about how java interpreter handles IncompatibleClassChangeError and nullPointerException.

Comment: It may be my limitation but I am unable to think about an exception without seeing the stack trace. Perhaps other experts here will be able to help. All the best.